# Why both “had” and “after” in “.... after we had completed our work”?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> We went to watch a movie after we had completed our work.

Why  the need for the word "had" when there is the word "after"?

Comment: There is no need for the word *"had"* when you use the word *"after";* anybody who told you this is wrong.  On the other hand, using the word *"had"* is also grammatically correct, because completing the work happened before you went to the movies.

Answer (score -2):

You would still have "had" if you used another term, even an opposite term, such as "before."

> *We went to watch a movie before we had completed our work.*

"Had" is required as a part of the [pluperfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluperfect) construction. "After" is a preposition, like would be "before," that signifies the temporal relationship between the clauses. It adds semantic value and as demonstrated is generally independent of the tense.

Comment: When I study this construction I had perceived that the need of "had" is to identify which action happened first. If so there is no need of "had"if th

Comment: if it follows "after, befor" etc.